# probability of a categorical column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, statistics

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
0 Age color country
1  23  red    Us
2  25  black  UK
3  19  blue   UK
4  10  red    India
5  15  red    UK
```

What I want to do is to find the probability of each category in 'color' column and have something like this:

```
0 Age color country  color_pro
1  23  red    Us       0.6 
2  25  black  UK       0.2
3  19  blue   UK       0.2
4  10  red    India    0.6
5  15  red    UK       0.6
```

What should I do for finding probability in a tuple?
like this:

```
0 color color_pro
1 red    0.6 
2 black  0.2
3 blue   0.2
4 red    0.6
5 red    0.6
```

I want to have the probability in another tuple:

```
0 color_pro
1  0.6 
2  0.2
3  0.2
4  0.6
5  0.6
```

Comment: Where is 0.75 for red coming from?

Comment: @SupratimHaldar sorry I changed it

Comment: I think all you need to do is use `pandas` `group_by` function to get the count of each color and divide by the length of your df.

Comment: Thanks @CFD. Have added a solution below, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `count` to get the values, then calculate proportion.

```
df['color_pro'] = df.groupby('color')['color'].transform('count')
df['color_pro'] = df['color_pro'].map(lambda x : x/len(df))
```

OR, clubbing both lines together, we can do this as well.

```
df['color_pro'] = df.groupby('color')['color'].transform(lambda x : x.count()/len(df))
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know how can I find a probability in a tuple with categorical values?

Comment: Can you show an example please, that'll to understand.

Comment: Looking at the example, I think you mean a new `Series` and not `tuple`. A tuple in Python is like array or list, but immutable. Anyways, for the desired output, you can simply do - `color_pro = df.groupby('color')['color'].transform(lambda x : x.count()/len(df))`. This will create a new Series and assign the values to it.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. What if there will be no dataframe any more? in case we want to find the probability of categorical datas in a series

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the last question clearly.